# How do you full text search an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket on S3 in which I have large amount of text files.

I want to search for some text within a text file. It contains raw data only.
And each text file has a different name.

For example, I have a bucket name:

**abc/myfolder/abac.txt**

**xyx/myfolder1/axc.txt**

& I want to search text like "I am human" in the above text files.

How to achieve this? Is it even possible?

Comment: You'd have to request all of the files one by one; it's not a relational database after all.

Comment: if i have 10 lack files. then my search will quite slow is it ?

Comment: Yeah, searching a million files will take some time; it's probably best to reconsider your options.

Comment: what about cloud search Api provided by AWS ?

Comment: you can, but you need to build a deligated tool for that. I plan to build one actually

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only way to do this will be via [CloudSearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/faqs/), which can use S3 as a source. It works using rapid retrieval to build an index. This should work very well but thoroughly check out the pricing model to make sure that this won't be too costly for you.

The alternative is as Jack said - you'd otherwise need to transfer the files out of S3 to an EC2 and build a search application there.

Answer (score 19):

Since [october 1st, 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/about-aws/whats-new/2015/10/introducing-amazon-elasticsearch-service/) Amazon offers another search service with Elastic Search, in more or less the same vein as cloud search you can [stream data from Amazon S3 buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es).

It will work with a lambda function to make sure any new data sent to an S3 bucket triggers an event notification to this Lambda and update the ES index.

All steps are well detailed in [amazon doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-aws-integrations.html#es-aws-integrations-s3-lambda-es) with Java and Javascript example.

At a high level, setting up to stream data to Amazon ES requires the following steps:

- Creating an Amazon S3 bucket and an Amazon ES domain
- Creating a Lambda deployment package.
- Configuring a Lambda function.
- Granting authorization to stream data to Amazon ES.

Answer (score 4):

Although not an AWS native service, there is [Mixpeek](https://mixpeek.com), which runs text extraction like Tika, Tesseract and ImageAI on your S3 files then places them in a Lucene index to make them searchable.

You integrate it as follows:

1. Download the module: https://github.com/mixpeek/mixpeek-python
2. Import the module and your API keys:

   ```
    from mixpeek import Mixpeek, S3
    from config import mixpeek_api_key, aws
   ```
3. Instantiate the S3 class (which uses boto3 and requests):

   ```
    s3 = S3(
        aws_access_key_id=aws['aws_access_key_id'],
        aws_secret_access_key=aws['aws_secret_access_key'],
        region_name='us-east-2',
        mixpeek_api_key=mixpeek_api_key
    )
   ```
4. Upload one or more existing S3 files:

   ```
        # upload all S3 files in bucket "demo"            
        s3.upload_all(bucket_name="demo")

        # upload one single file called "prescription.pdf" in bucket "demo"
        s3.upload_one(s3_file_name="prescription.pdf", bucket_name="demo")
   ```
5. Now simply search using the Mixpeek module:

   ```
        # mixpeek api direct
        mix = Mixpeek(
            api_key=mixpeek_api_key
        )
        # search
        result = mix.search(query="Heartgard")
        print(result)
   ```
6. Where result can be:

   ```
    [
        {
            "_id": "REDACTED",
            "api_key": "REDACTED",
            "highlights": [
                {
                    "path": "document_str",
                    "score": 0.8759502172470093,
                    "texts": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "value": "Vetco Prescription\nVetcoClinics.com\n\nCustomer:\n\nAddress: Canine\n\nPhone: Australian Shepherd\n\nDate of Service: 2 Years 8 Months\n\nPrescription\nExpiration Date:\n\nWeight: 41.75\n\nSex: Female\n\n℞  "
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "hit",
                            "value": "Heartgard"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "value": " Plus Green 26-50 lbs (Ivermectin 135 mcg/Pyrantel 114 mg)\n\nInstructions: Give one chewable tablet by mouth once monthly for protection against heartworms, and the treatment and\ncontrol of roundworms, and hookworms. "
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "date_inserted": "2021-10-07 03:19:23.632000",
                "filename": "prescription.pdf"
            },
            "score": 0.13313256204128265
        }
    ]
   ```

Then you parse the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filestash](https://github.com/mickael-kerjean/filestash) (*Disclaimer*: I'm the author), install you own instance and connect to your S3 bucket. Eventually give it a bit of time to index the entire thing if you have a whole lot of data and you should be good

Comment: Does Filestash search .gz files also?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an EMR, then create a spark application and do a search . We did this. This will work as distributed searcn

Answer (score -1):

I know this is really old, but hopefully someone find my solution handy.

This is a python script, using boto3.

```
def search_word (info, search_for):
    res = False
    if search_for in info:
        res = True
    elif search_for not in info:
        res = False   
    return res

import boto3
import json

aws_access_key_id='AKIAWG....'
aws_secret_access_key ='p9yrNw.....'
client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key)
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'my.bucket.name'
bucket_prefix='2022/05/'
search_for = 'looking@emailaddress.com'
search_results = []
search_results_keys = []

response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=bucket_name,
    Prefix=bucket_prefix
)

for i in response['Contents']:
    mini = {}
    obj = client.get_object(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=i['Key']
    )
    body = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    key = i['Key']
    if search_word(body, search_for):
        mini = {}
        mini[key] = body
        search_results.append(mini)
        search_results_keys.append(key)

# YOU CAN EITHER PRINT THE KEY (FILE NAME/DIRECTORY), OR A MAP WHERE THE KEY IS THE FILE NAME/DIRECTORY. AND THE VALUE IS THE TXT OF THE FILE 
print(search_results)
print(search_results_keys)
```

Answer (score -1):

there is serverless and cheaper option available

1. Use AWS Glue and you can convert the txt fils into a table
2. use AWS AThena and you can run sql queries on top of it.

I wouldrecommend you to put data in parquets on s3 and this makes the data size on s3 very small and super fast!