# How to search a string in Amazon S3 files?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have all types of files or documents stored in Amazon S3.

How to perform search on those documents using a search keyword or string (full-text search, if possible) ?

Is there any documentum built on it ?

Matching documents list which has the search string will be displayed to the user for download.

Any help please ?

Comment: Please look my answer

Comment: Things have changed a little now, AWS's Athena can help if your files are of a certain format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129914/121946

Answer (score 3):

Searching documents in S3 is not possible.

S3 is not a document database.  It is an  object store, designed for storing data but inferring no "meaning" from the data -- essentially a key/value store suporting very large values.  It has no sense of context.  It doesn't index the content of the objects, or even the object metadata.  The only way to "find" an object in S3 is to already know its key.

It is excellent for highly available and highly reliable storage, but searching not part of its design.

Comment: nowadays AWS Athena is very powerful to search S3 data across files.

Comment: @DenisWang that is true.  There's no need to downvote answers that were correct at the time they were written.  A comment will suffice.  I will plan to update this.

Comment: yeah. you are right. sorry for that. i will re-vote once you update it.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions depends on how structured your S3 file data is. 
If it is structured or semi-structured like cvs, JSON with columnar alike format, AWS Athena will be the best choice. With just a few clicks, you’re ready to query your S3 files.

Otherwise, if the data is totally un-structured, you may want to use elasticsearch and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cant search as you wish in amazon S3.
but we have alternate solution for this. I am using S3 browser software for this.

**here is link to download: http://s3browser.com/**

Download it and you will have all access same like amazon S3 browser. you can also perform search and other processes.

Comment: "We?"  Are you affiliated with this product?

Comment: No, I am just helping you as what I do in one of my service. I am not promoting any product.

Comment: I am not promoting my product and it is not mine. I am just helping you. I am using it so I am refering you this

Comment: Do you know of a similar app for Mac?