# How to search files using text inside in Lravel/S3?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, amazon-s3

I'm using **Laravel7** with **Aws-S3** as file storage. 
The files are **PDF** only and and I want to add **search files feature** i.e. If a user search for a text, I want to list all PDF files that has the matching text.

Is this something possible using Laravel alone or using Aws/S3? 
I know I can extract all the text of a file on upload and store it in database, and when user search for a text, I can search it from database using `%LIKE%` query but this will take a huge database space.

I'm looking for something better.

Comment: I mean the other option is to load file after file and load the text out of the file and search through it. Therefore I assume that saving the content on upload will be faster than reading in the PDFs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to search for file contents in amazon S3 bucket without downloading the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127131/how-to-search-for-file-contents-in-amazon-s3-bucket-without-downloading-the-file)